# Deleting multiple intents with watson-developer-cloud nodejs sdk

Tags: node.js, ibm-cloud, ibm-watson, watson-conversation, watson-assistant

I'm using watson-developer-cloud with nodejs and trying to delete more than `intent` with the following:

```
let IntentName = req.body.intentName;
var params = {
workspace_id: workspaceId,
intent: // delete more than on intent here
 };

conversation.deleteIntent(params, function(err, response) {
   if (err) {
    console.error(err);
  } else {
    console.log(JSON.stringify(response, null, 2));
  }
 });
```

how can i delete more than one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One option you can do is download the whole workspace and work on the JSON object directly. Then when completed, send the whole updated block back to your workspace in one go.

This means less calls, lowering your chances of a rate limit kicking in.

Comment: is there an API by which I can get all the workspace data ? 
there is one with which we can only list its name and basic data. how can I get everything about the workspace

Comment: When you use the API to get the information on a workspace, you set `export=true`. https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/assistant/api/v1/node.html?node#get-workspace

Comment: A tool (not by IBM, not maintained) to work with workspaces https://github.com/data-henrik/watson-conversation-tool/

Answer (score 1):

The [SDK](https://github.com/watson-developer-cloud/) is based on the [API for Watson Assistant](https://www.ibm.com/watson/developercloud/assistant/api/v1/curl.html?curl#delete-intent). The API supports deletion of one intent per call. So you would need to loop over all the intents you want to delete and remove them one by one.